# Looking for a storage case for multiple hard drives

Tags: hard-disk

I'm looking for ideally one or a few containers that can store and reasonably protect hard drives sitting in the closet, and that would be easy to pick up and set in a car to transport if needed.

I have around 10-15 older 3.5" internal hard drives and around five 2.5" internal hard drives sitting around in the closet.

I'm not too worried about it being ruggedized or shock resistant, just something simple and inexpensive and better than cardboard boxes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is blatantly off topic.  This is more or less asking for a box to put stuff in.

Comment: Are you looking for a piece of luggage or something to connect all of these drives? Very unclear

Comment: @NZKshatriya, I would suggest voting to get the Help for this site improved or at least clarified if this question doesn't suit your tastes. Based on my interpretation of the current Help, this question is on-topic or at least not off-topic. If you disagree, you're welcome to provide evidence along with your vote.

Comment: Our current definition of hardware, is something that electronically connects or communicates with a computer.  A storage box does neither.

Comment: @jia103, This question is being discussed on [meta](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/606/are-storage-crates-for-hard-drives-on-topic). May I suggest you provide input there. It seems that the existing answer present indicates this should be off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of options. I ended up going with a [Hard Disk Drive Shipping Box - Slotted Storage Container Package](http://www.tssgrp.com/index.php/products/packaging-supplies-for-computer-a-it-products) from Tek Source Solutions. This ended up costing around $35 on eBay and they claim it will hold 20-24 3.5" drives or I can double them up to store 40-48 2.5" drives.

I don't have that many, so I can use this to store the few drives I have and maybe fill up the rest of the box with other similar sized cards, RAM, etc.

Another item I found was the [HDD Paper Storage Box with Cover (5-Bay)](https://usb.brando.com/hdd-paper-storage-box-with-cover-5-bay-_p00962c0044d015.html) from Brando Workshop. This was a modest $16 to hold five 3.5" drives.

Both of these are primarily simple cardboard boxes, so I'll probably leave the hardware in its respective anti-static bags while in the box.

What I wanted to get was one of the foam containers from [ProStorage](https://getprostorage.com/store/) such as their ProStorage18, but it's $80. It looks like the entire container is anti-static, so I imagine I wouldn't need the drives stored in their anti-static bags if I got this.

Comment: A shipping box is not hardware,.